# Clearing Telerik RadSpreadSheet for WPF Control

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using a Telerik RadSpreadSheet in a WPF application to display different pieces of data. Between each set of data I clear the spreadsheet. The only way I've found to do this is clearing each cell. This works, but it feels wrong. Is there a better solution?

```
for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < columnCount; y++) {
    radSpreadsheet.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[x, y].SetValue("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
radSpreadsheet.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[0, 0, rowCount - 1, columnCount - 1]?.ClearValue();
```